# How I can sketch the proof of consistency of only one beta in multiple regression?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, least-squares, estimators

Now assume you additionally obtained data on average parental incomes (PI) and the ethnic composition (EC) of the pupils in school. You regress the score on

- STR
- PI
- EC and
- a constant.

State the main assumption for consistent estimation of the coefficient on STR. Assume a linear setting and sketch a proof for consistency of the OLS estimator for the coefficient on STR.

Normally, I use matrix form for this kind of question, then how can I prove for only one beta, I was thinking about Frisch-Waugh-Theorem but i cannot move on to proof it. Any idea ?